# How to represent user rights in a elegant way?

Tags: php, authentication

Here is the table of user rights

```
Post
        Guest User                      Admin 
Create    N     Y                         Y
Read      Y     Y                         Y
Update    N   Their own post ONLY        All
Delete    N     N (yes, user can't del)   Y
```

And here is the situation. I am thinking putting all the validating user rights in one single class to handle. And all the action have a defined name, for example: create_post, read_post. Also, have a user_role to pass in, let say: role_guest, role_user. And the validation class do all the magic. What do you think of this design? Thank you.

Comment: You could use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

If all your permissions are (or can be generalised to) a set of yes/no conditions, it's quite easy.

In your example, you have Create, Read, Update and Delete. That's 4 bits, so you need a 4-bit number to store permissions. (0000 to 1111 in binary = 0 to 15 in decimal)

Someone who can only read would have permissions 0100 (4 in decimal), and someone who can create/read/update would have persmissions 1110 (14 in decimal). Administrators who have full access would have persmissions 1111 (15 in decimal).

The way you would check these in PHP would be with the bitwise OR operator `|`.

For example

```
// you could write a function getUserPermission($strUsername)
// which returns a permission number, say 10 (1010 in binary)
// which means he/she can create/update but not read/delete
$userPermissions = getUserPermission("TedWong");

$permissionCreate = 8; // 1000;
$permissionRead   = 4; // 0100;
$permissionUpdate = 2; // 0010;
$permissionDelete = 1; // 0001;

if ($userPermissions | $permissionCreate)
{
  //user has permission to create
}

if ($userPermissions | $permissionRead)
{
  //User has permission to read
}

if (!($userPermissions | $permissionDelete))
{
  //User doesn't have permission to delete
}

if ($userPermissions | $permissionUpdate &&
    $userPermissions | $permissionCreate)
{
  //User has permission to create and update.
}
```

If you want more permissions, you just need to introduce more bits.

As for your update all posts/delete own posts in your example, I would have a 5-bit permission structure: Create, Read, Delete, UpdateOwn, UpdateAll.

You can have many permissions, but would be limited by the data structure storing them. For example, if you are storing the permission mask in a 32-bit integer, then you can only have up to 32 permissions.

here is a full list of 4-bit permissions for your example:

```
0000 //  0: No Permissions
0001 //  1: Delete
0010 //  2: Update
0011 //  3: Delete + Update
0100 //  4: Read
0101 //  5: Read + Delete
0110 //  6: Read + Update
0111 //  7: Read + Delete + Update
1000 //  8: Create
1001 //  9: Create + Delete
1010 // 10: Create + Update
1011 // 11: Create + Delete + Update
1100 // 12: Create + Read
1101 // 13: Create + Read + Delete
1110 // 14: Create + Read + Update
1111 // 15: Create + Read + Delete + Update
```

So that means the *INTEGER* **6** (which in *BINARY* is equal to **0110**) gives permissions Read/Update but not Create/Delete. In the same way each *integer* has a set of permissions associated with it. You can store up to as many permissions in the integer as many bits there are that represent that integer (usually 32).

So you can see that with a 4-bit integer (decimal numbers 0 to 15) can give you 4 yes/no permissions. If you use a 32-but integer then you can have up to 32 yes/no permissions.

Check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) on how to determine the maximum size of your integers. (It depends on the platform you're running your PHP parser on). I think generally speaking a 32-bit system/OS will allow for 32-bit integers, and 64-bit system/OS will allow for 64-bit integers.

Check [these other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+bitmask+permissions) on SO for discussions on pros/cons of using bitmasks vs other methods.

Comment: I see, but how many permission I can have? I see that is multiple in next permission, will it become a super big int? if I have the right of read and update ONLY, and my permission is 6, right?

Comment: No, if you have 4 permissions then you have a 4-bit bitmask = 0-15. If you have 5 permissions then you have 0-31. 6 permissions = 0-63, etc. In the example you gave, each user will have a decimal permission number between 0 and 15 only. 0 means no permission, 15 means all permissions.

Comment: why it is not 6? read is 4, and update is 2...I have these two, why it is not 6?

Comment: sosad, my application may need much more than 32 permission, any workaround, I find that way is elegant.

Comment: No. Read is 0100 and update is 0010. Someone who can read and update has permissions 0110. I'm going to update the answer with a full list so you can understand clearer.

Comment: @Ozzah how does this work? I tried using it, and it always return true for all if check